# Database update SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Suppose I have the following table

**MemberTable**

```
ID (1 letter + 5 digits) | Name | Type
```

And I have the following records

```
A00000 | Peter | A 
B00001 | Amy   | B 
C00002 | Susan | A
...
```

Now I need to update all the ID base on the follow criteria:

1. All start with `00-`
2. Then comes with 2 digits base on the member type
3. Then add back the original ID except the 1st letter

Member type digits mapping

```
A -> 00 
B -> 01 
C -> 02
```

There the following would be the data I suppose to have after update

```
00-0000000 | Peter | A 
00-0100001 | Amy   | B 
00-0000002 | Susan | A
```

Suppose the mapping only a document reference, ie. do not have a table store the mapping details.

Any suggested update statement? Thanks for help.

Comment: Dont use sql use c++.

Comment: Sigh, why do people put all that HTML markup in the question, instead of using the SO code formatting tool? I was going to reformat it, but it's too much trouble editing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which DBMS, this is a MySQL answer:

```
update MemberTable
set id = concat('00-',
                case Type
                    when 'A' then '00'
                    when 'B' then '01'
                    when 'C' then '02'
                end,
                substr(id, 2))
```

The syntax for other databases will be slightly different, but the basic idea should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are using SQL Server, you can try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID VARCHAR(20),
        [Type] VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A00000','A'),('B00001','B'),('C00002','A')

SELECT  *,
        '00-' + 
        CASE
            [Type] 
             WHEN 'A' THEN '00'
             WHEN 'B' THEN '01'
             WHEN 'C' THEN '02'
        END +
                        SUBSTRING(ID,2,LEN(ID)-1)
FROM    @Table
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18872)